# Looking for specific incremental backup software for Windows

Tags: backup

Most Windows proprietary applications use proprietary databases which are impossible to study, modify or anything unless you're using the application which created them which limits your options in terms of organizing backups. Backup storage itself may also fail in various ways which means the backup database may become corrupted and the entire set of backups becomes random noise.

What I'm looking for is a software which does this. Given the source directory `A` we first copy it to the destination `B/Full` (as as, directories and files).

Every interval, let's say each day, the software does something like this:

```
B/20221028/Added
B/20221028/Modified
B/20221028/Removed
```

Next day:

```
B/20221029/Added
B/20221029/Modified
B/20221029/Removed
```

Where "Added" contains newly created files vs `[Source + 20221028]`, "Modified" contains modified files vs `[Source + 20221028]`, and "Removed" contains *empty* files which indicate which source files have been removed vs `[Source + 20221028]` or a simple text files which lists deleted files.

I'm OK if the application keeps track of all the files and their states using its own database because calculating incremental updates only based off files could become a task which takes forever if we are talking about hundreds of thousands of files.

Is there anything under Windows which works this way? I don't care if it's proprietary or open source. I just want backups to be manageable using any file management software.